# How to write unit_test for a function which only updates a global dict type variable - Python(pytest)

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

Unit-Test code for a function which does a validation operation and updates the Global dict - **`result_count = {'test_method':{'Total_tested': 0, 'passed': 0, 'failed': 0}`**

below is the function

```
def validate_response(testmethod, response, expected_data):

    ra = response.json()

    expected = expected_data['payload']

    if (response.status_code == expected['response_status']) \
         and (result_count[testmethod['folder']]["FAILED"] < 10):    

         ------code logic - checks using jsondiff and re.expressions--

    else:
        missmatch = 'response status code missmatch'
        update_result(testmethod, 'status_code', expected_data, response, missmatch, fail=True)
        result_count[testmethod['folder']]['FAILED'] += 1
```

Need to write test for the above function. to check if the result_count is updated properly.

Regular expression library & jsondiff is also used in the mentioned function.

help required for mocking the global variable and using the same for testing.

During executing the test script below i was getting a key error for the global variable result_count. That implies that the code is unable to access the result_count.. the key error after the update - is throwing *TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'MagicMock' and 'int'* **as Error**
The current issue is that the result_count is not updated when the below line code is executed.

```
partner_test.validate_response(test_input_mocker.method, response, expected_data)
```

my unit test script is as below

```
@patch("tests.p_test.result")
@patch("tests.p_test.result_count")
def test_validate_response_pass(result_count_mocker, monkeypatch, result_mocker, test_input_mocker):

# Build data for validate response function

response = Resp(200, {'message': 'pong'})
response_data = response.json()
expected_data = {some_test_data}

# global variable import and initialize result, result_count
from p_test import result, result_count
result_count.update(result_count_mocker.data)
result.update(result_mocker.data)
result_count_mocker.return_value = result_count_mocker.data

def update_result_mocker(*args):
    mock operations here
    return None

monkeypatch.setattr(partner_test, "update_result", update_result_mocker)
p_test.validate_response(test_input_mocker.method, response, expected_data)
```

Resp() in the test fnction is a response class created to mock the response object.

Comment: You might be patching the wrong thing. What is the module path where you have your `validate_response` defined?

Comment: @AniaWarzecha the validate_response is inside my integration_test/tests/ folder in partner_test.py file

Comment: @ I have updated the code adding the line ..    from partner_test import result, result_count
resolves the issue of global variable access. But my variables are not updated as expected. I  think i am calling the line 
    in a wrong way partner_test.validate_response(test_input_mocker.method, response, expected_data)

Comment: @AniaWarzecha I have made some update in the question at the unit testscript  file

Comment: resolved and answerred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue can be resolved using @patch.dict(dict_name, values) below is the solution

```
@patch.dict(p_test.result, {dict_values })
@patch.dict(p_test.result_count, {dict_values})
def test_validate_response(monkeypatch, test_input_mocker, result_count_test):
    response = Resp(200, {'message': 'pong'})
    response_data = response.json()

    expected_data = {----your data-----}

    def update_result_mocker(*args):
        # mock_operations


    monkeypatch.setattr(p_test, "update_result", update_result_mocker)
    p_test.validate_response(test_input_mocker.method, response, expected_data)
    print(p_test.result_count)
```